# Shell script to find file older than 4 days and move

Tags: shell, ksh

How I can include files older than 4 days in below code?

Tried testing few variations with "-mtime +3" but it gives me syntax error. Function to see if file exits and move if older than 4 days old.

```
#!/bin/ksh
FILE=test.txt
 if [ -f "$FILE" ]
   then mv "$FILE" "$FILE.old"
 fi
```

I have searched many threads and all uses find command.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find . -mtime +3` works:

```
$ cd -- "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ touch --date='4 days ago' old
$ touch new
$ find . -mtime +3
./old
```

Have you tried that variation? If so, which `find` do you have?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replied, it helped in resolving tricky part, appreciate it.